# Is there a way to use Panache in Quarkus in a "standalone way"

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

I use Quarkus for my backend application since few months and today i have a specific use case :
I have a lot of database (sqlite) and it's not possible for me to specify all of this database in the application.propertie. So, i wrote some code, using agroal, to access to my database. The thing is that, if I do that, i am wondering how i can mix that with panache ?

Panache & panache entity is really nice and easy to use, but in my case, i'm a little bit on the edge of the framework and i can't find a good way to do what i need.
By managing my databases by myself and agroal as a pool, it's "low level" and i can't find how to use the power of Panache instead of writing all SQL query by hand.

Thank'a a lot.

Comment: Currently, Hibernate with Panache only allow to access the default database configured inside your application.properties.
Hibernate multi persistence unit is currently not supported but there is plans to support it in a near future.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any idea about what you call "near future" please ? Or is there a roadmap where i can see something about that. I made some research but didn't find nothing.

Comment: The roadmap is here: https://github.com/orgs/quarkusio/projects/5#card-35216897
Multiple persistence unit support is planned for 1.7 (August). Be aware that the support on Panache can be done a little later.